# Can I define dynamic volume groups and use them as variables across azure pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have to define the variable group dynamically based on branch name and I also have to update the volume group at end of pipeline. For that, I need to access variable group name as parameter.

I am trying with below approach and is not working. is there any other way to handle this?

```
variables:
- ${{ if startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/users') }}:
  - name: variableGroupName
    value: userbranches
- ${{ else }}:
  - name: variableGroupName
    value: $ [ variables ['Build.SourceBranchName'] ]
- group: $(variableGroupName)
```

Comment: Did you try using a compile-time expression `${{ variables['Build.SourceBranchName'] }}` instead of a runtime expression (`$[]`)?

Comment: Yes. it keeps giving me
`There was a resource authorization issue: "An error occurred while loading the YAML build pipeline. Variable group was not found or is not authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz."`